# Number directive to support decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have written a directive for text input, to support int values.

Here is it

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HostListener, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  exportAs: 'number-directive',
  selector: 'number-directive, [number-directive]'
})
export class NumberDirective {
  private el: NgControl;
  constructor(ngControl: NgControl) {
    this.el = ngControl;
  }
  // Listen for the input event to also handle copy and paste.
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  onInput(value: string) {
    // Use NgControl patchValue to prevent the issue on validation
    this.el.control.patchValue(value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  }
}
```

And HTML

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ l("RoomWidth") }}</label>
                    <input
                        decimal-number-directive
                        #roomWidthInput="ngModel"
                        class="form-control nospinner-input"
                        type="text"
                        name="roomWidth"
                        [(ngModel)]="room.roomWidth"
                        maxlength="32"
                    />
                </div>
```

But I need it to support decimal values. For example 99.5

How do I need to modify it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476131/7124761) regex?

Comment: Can you provide stacblitz?

Comment: are you replacing `0-9` numbers with empty string?

Comment: Now I replacing all symbols by empty string and writing only numbers @PrashantPimpale

Comment: please provide related html and Ts code

Comment: Updated my code @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Post the TS code?

Comment: It's already posted @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Do you want to allow user to type only decimal numbers?

Comment: yes. like 99.5, etc. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Then use Regular expression in FormControl? Why do you want that to be done with Directive? Or may be pattern?

Comment: Because I think it's better. Anyway, how to write Regexp for this in directive? @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtuvhw Do you want this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
onInput(value: string) {
  // Use NgControl patchValue to prevent the issue on validation
  this.el.control.patchValue(value.replace(/[^0-9].[^0-9]/g, ''));
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtuvhw)

Comment: It helps. Thank's
Also little question, how I can limit number after `.` to 2 digits?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have need to considerate two consegutive point too and replace caracter. Maybe is writable with regex but this work for me.
Example if you type or paste 45.456.6 it will be repaced with 45.4566

```
 @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    let initalValue: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    initalValue = initalValue.replace(/[^\.|0-9]/g, '');
    // elimina le seconde occorrenze del punto
    const count = (initalValue.match(/\./g) || []).length;
    for (let i = 1; i < count; i++) {
      initalValue = this.repaceSecondDotOccurrence(initalValue);
    }
    this.el.nativeElement.value = initalValue;
  }


  repaceSecondDotOccurrence(inputString): string {
    let t = 0;
    return inputString.replace(/\./g, function (match) {
      t++;
      return (t === 2) ? '' : match;
    });
  }
```